# How to get the value of all elements with a certain attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get the value of all elements with a certain attribute.

I have a lot elements like this one

```
<input data-ini="3" class="form-control" type="time">
```

The attribute is day_of_week_ini, where i'm going to receive a day of the week in a function like this one

```
function createNewPeriod(day_of_week){
    //i should have all values inside an array
}
```

//EDIT

I need to do that with jquery

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('input[day_of_week_ini]')].map(...)`

Comment: your html is invalid. use data attribute : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: *"I need to do that with jQuery"* <= `$('input[day_of_week_ini]').map(...).get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*input[data-ini] is the css selector. second parameter of jQuery map function is DOM element, so we retrieved the attr value using jquery. $(element) convert the DOM element to jQuery object.*/
var a = $('input[data-ini]').map((index,element)=> $(element).attr('data-ini'));
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <!-- A series of html time controls with data attribute data-ini -->
    <input data-ini="3" class="form-control" type="time" value="18:00">
    <input data-ini="4" class="form-control" type="time" value="16:00">
    <input data-ini="5" class="form-control" type="time" value="02:00">
    <input data-ini="6" class="form-control" type="time" value="03:00">
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use data attribute for cases like this as developer said and set value attribute for your elements as it is edited now.
Then you can use below jQuery code.

```
var allElements = jQuery("[data-ini]");
var myArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(allElements[i].val());
}
```